# Why does SmartScreen still warn me after signing with an EV certificate?

Tags: code-signing

I recently bought an EV Code Signing Certificate from [GoDaddy](https://uk.godaddy.com/web-security/code-signing-certificate) (they call it a Driver Signing Certificate though, but it [should be equivalent](https://uk.godaddy.com/community/SSL-And-Security/driver-signing-certificate-vs-EV-code-signing-certificate/td-p/51388) to an EV certificate and they also state that the Driver Signing Certificate "Eliminates security warnings during download and installation" aka SmartScreen warnings) and signed both my EXE files and MSI installer using:

```
signtool.exe" sign /v /fd sha256 /td sha256 /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com /f Cert.pdf /p password Application.exe/Installer.msi
```

After downloading the installer (using Chrome/Edge) from one of our servers I still get the SmartScreen warning, however (it shows the company name, though)? EV certificates are supposed to establish instant reputation with SmartScreen, but it doesn't - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a chat session with GoDaddy support I now have conflicting information (in relation to the linked post in my original question):

- GoDaddy Driver Signing Certificate is *not* the same as an EV Code Signing Certificate.
- GoDaddy Driver Signing Certificate will *not* remove the SmartScreen warning immediately.

I assume this to be the more correct statements given that the SmartScreen warning is still shown when trying to install using our signed MSI file.

I assume it would still work given enough time for reputation to be built.

Comment: Hello @Woodgnome, I face the same issue. Was the warning removed after enough time for reputation to be built ?

Comment: @AloïsdeLaComble eventually, yes!